# Verify that $A$ satisfies the stated conditions and find the angle of rotation.

Tags: linear-algebra

It can be proved that if $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with orthonormal column vectors and for which $\text{det}(A)=1$, then multiplication by $A$ is a rotation through some angle $\theta$. Verify that 
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\[0.3em] 
\phantom{-}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfies the stated conditions and find the angle of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Rotation matrices always have orthonormal column vectors and determinant $1$. Observe that
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \frac{4\pi}{3} && -\sin \frac{4\pi}{3} \\ \sin \frac{4\pi}{3} && \cos \frac{4\pi}{3} \end{bmatrix}
$$
The verifications should be easy. Hint: Do them in trigonometric form and let $\theta$ be the angle. It is much easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

You just calculate the determinant and the dot products of the columns with one another to do the first part. For the second part, just apply the matrix to the unit x-vector and use trigonometry (it's a very familiar triangle) to see what angle it's been rotated through.

Comment: So $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) =0$ and det(A)=$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}=1$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.